# Best practice to store server connection data in Android

Tags: android, properties, sharedpreferences, config

I'm thinking about where to store the connection data to the server. This could include a URL and port, maybe more.

I thought the best for this would be to create something like a file in `/assets` called "config.properties". However, while doing research I did find out this is not the most popular way. But my impression is that it's bad practice to save data like this hardcoded in a static class. And also the "preferences" are more made for configurations the user can change, or for information gathered during runtime (like the user's login data or a login token).

Is there a common way how to do it? In the best case with something like a "configuration"-file?

Comment: [`/res/values/whatevernameyoulike.xml`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where do you wanna use these values. If it's only used in a single class taking care of your connections you could simply have all this as class attributes.